# netbeans: How to put some title in the title bar

Tags: java, netbeans

I developed a small desktop application in Net Beans. When i run my application there appears no title in the Windows Title bar. Is there anyway through which i specify some title which later on will appear in Windows title bar? Following is my Main method

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                new MyJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: @Pratik: for creating UI, I first add JFrame and then drag and drop all control on it
public class MyJPane extends javax.swing.JFrame { . . . }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the title bar at JFrame initialization time like this

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("My Title");
```

or you can create public method for your custom class like

```
public void setTitle(String title){
    frame.setTitle(title); // for this you have declare the frame object as global for this class only
}
```

and use like this way

```
MyJFrame myframe = new MyJFrame();
myframe.setTitle("my new title");
myframe.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 5):

[image: Setting title in JFrame Netbeans Swing]

You can see title property in properties window (Bottom right side). You can set title upon clicking that property. 
If you are unable to find property window, just click on Design tab and then on blank JFrame GUI.

Answer (score 2):

```
myTopLevelContainer = new myTopLevelContainer("myTitlaLabel");
```

or

```
myTopLevelContainer.setTitle("myTitlaLabel");
```

Comment: @Jame `JFrame`, `JDialog` or (very old AWT Components from last milenium) Frame and Dialog, more about Top Level Container http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html

Answer (score 1):

From the [NetBeans Wiki](http://wiki.netbeans.org/SDIAppNetBeans):

> To give your application a title, right click on the JFrame and open its properties dialog box. Click the properties tab.

**Under the Properties tab, find and modify the `title` field.**  NetBeans will do the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this worked for me ...

```
public yourGUIname() {
    initComponents();
    this.setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getClass().getResource("your image here")));
    this.setTitle("your title here"); // that is the code you looking for
}
```

so what I did was put the above code in the generated public method.